# Error: Too Many Values to Unpack (Python)

Tags: python, graph, max, mean

i'm using python 2.7.3

this is a snippet of my code:

```
linematchregex = re.compile('(\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+), (\d+\.\d+)')
.
.
with open(r'temp.txt', 'r') as f:
     f.next()
     t,temp = zip(*[p for line in for p in linematchregex.findall(line)])
     groups = itertools.groupby(f, lambda row row[0].split()[0])
     for date, group in groups:
               group = [(datetime.strptime(dt), value)
                       **for dt, value in group]**
               during_8to5 = {len(value) for value in group
                             if datetime.time(8) <= dt.time() < datetime.time(17)}
      .
      .
      .
      .
      long_title = {'\n Max AMB_TEMP Value: {:.2f} at {}, Min AMB_TEMP Value: {:.2f} at  
      {}, Mean AMB_TEMP Value: {:.2f} at {}')
      ax1.set_title(long_title.format(max(group),min(group),sum(during_8to5)/len(during_8to5))
```

when i run the module, i get 'for dt, value in group' i get 'too many values to unpack'

fyi, my txt file data is: 21/7/2014 0:00,0.66,29.16 
so should i put ' split(',') ' since my data is separated by a comma?
and since my time is in h:m format by putting just 8 and 17 is it okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your values in "group" are probably not all of equal length. Consider the following simple example:

```
>>> a, b = 1, 2, 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Now, I think what you want is:

```
>>> [ (a, b) for a, b in [[1,2],[3,4], [5,6]] ]
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

But what happens is:

```
>>> [ (a, b) for a, b in [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7]] ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

You could quickly double-check via something simple like:

```
during_8to5 = {len(vals) for vals in group
                             if datetime.time(8) <= dt.time() < datetime.time(17)}

print(during_8to5)
```

If the resulting set does not consist of a single value, you know where the problems lies.

### EDIT:

I may have looked in the from line, since you are using

```
for dt, value in group
```

in 2 locations. What if you just use a debugger like pdb, move the printing of the `len` up one level, or use an `try-except` to print the length of `group` if an `ValueError` occurs and exit the program.

Comment: hi Sebastian, thank you very very much for replying, but when i run my module i got an error saying ' ax1.set_title ' line got a name error: name ' group ' is not defined

Comment: I assume that the asterisks in the line `**for dt, value in group]**` are only for highlighting purposes on Stackoverflow?

Comment: ya i just put that to make easier to see, do you need the full code?

Comment: i also found out if i put the ax1.set_title line down below the 
during_8to5 line it will run without error but it will not show the max/min or mean

Comment: Basically, you solved this issue already in another line earlier (or found a workaround) via `t,temp = zip(*[p...`, you basically have to do the same thing at those places where you get the error for unpacking the values of `group`. Maybe it would be most helpful to see how the subitems in `groups` looks like.

Comment: is the subitems you refering to my .txt file?

Comment: hi Sebastian, i guessing it refer to my .txt file
i have posted it on my OP along with my entire code

Comment: hi Sebastian, i'm sorry but i dont quite get what you mean about the zip line, right now, i have a syntax error at the line, ' for date, group in groups: ..' the program highlight the semi-colon in red